# C# DataGridView programmatically changed selection appearance

Tags: c#, datagridview

[image]

While programming I've found out that when I select a row programmatically, it selects the row and highlihgts it however the black arrow on the left does not move.
Then it moves when I left-click it to select it manually again.

Could be just a silly question, but it makes me curious.

I wonder if that's how it's meant to be, or would there be any way I can control the black arrow?

Thank you for reading a beginner's question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DataGridView.SelectedRows` and `DataGridView.CurrentRow` are two distinct properties. One is used to control highlighted rows, whereas the othe ris used to control the black arrow.

In addition to the above, there is `DataGridView.SelectedCells` too, using which you can select less than a row, or arbitrary non-contiguous selection of cells.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! :)